# Can't Read from a file

Tags: c, file-io

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why this won't work:

```
fprintf(stdout, "filename: %s\n", filename); // looks great

// open the requested file
if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to open file: %s\n", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Successfully opened file: %s\n", filename);
}

do {
    bzero(buffer, BUFFSIZE);  // size 1024 bytes
    bytes_read = fread( &buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFSIZE, fd );
    fprintf(stdout, "buffer contents: %s\n", buffer);
} while (!feof(fd));

fclose(fd);
```

This is my output:

```
filename: test.txt
Successfully opened file: test.txt
buffer contents: 
buffer contents: 
buffer contents: 009
BEGIN_LINE010This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE010
```

---

Note that it has completely 'lost' the first 8+ lines from the text file. It clearly opened the file and read the last line (plus the trailing 3 characters from the 9th line). Where did these other lines go? I'm totally at a loss.

Here is the entirety of the test file that I am trying to read:

```
BEGIN_LINE000This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE000
BEGIN_LINE001This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE001
BEGIN_LINE002This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE002
BEGIN_LINE003This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE003
BEGIN_LINE004This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE004
BEGIN_LINE005This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE005
BEGIN_LINE006This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE006
BEGIN_LINE007This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE007
BEGIN_LINE008This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE008
BEGIN_LINE009This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE009
BEGIN_LINE010This is a test file with exactly 10 lines of readable textEND_LINE010
```

Comment: i think code you posted has some syntax error...

Comment: Where? It compiles for me.

Comment: i think you have missed something in this line `fprintf(stdout, "buffer contents: %s\n"`

Comment: fprintf(stdout, "buffer contents: %s\n", you opened file in binart mode, and expecting it to print the string, Read about file opening modes,

Comment: are you using turbo C??

Comment: Oops. You're right. I fixed it.

Comment: I've tried it with and without binary mode. I'd rather do it without binary mode, but I can't get that to work.

Comment: You should check the return value from `fread()` before you assume there's anything to print.

Comment: You're opening a text file as binary file. Please replace `fopen(filename, "rb")` with `fopen(filename, "r")`.

Comment: @SAK How did you reformat my file contents? That's what I was wondering about in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this code:

```
   FILE *fp;
   char buff[255];

   char *filename="input.txt";

   fprintf(stdout, "filename: %s\n", filename); // looks great

   if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) 
   {
        fprintf(stdout, "Failed to open file: %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }   
   else 
   {
        fprintf(stdout, "Successfully opened file: %s\n", filename);
   }   
   while ( !feof(fp ) )
   {
        memset(buff, '\0', sizeof( buff) );
        fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
        printf("%s", buff );
   }
   fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It almost works. It misses the first two lines and correctly prints the last 8 lines. Weird...

Comment: plz post the content of file too. Thx

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in a nicely formatted way? If I just copy and paste it, it is hard to read.

Comment: just post top 15 lines or something

Comment: @usr55410 edit the file into your question, not SAK's answer.

Comment: is there something else you are trying to do, as this code works fine here with the file contents that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is often not a good idea to mix opening a file in text mode with using fread()

If you open the file in binary mode "rb" instead then fread should work as expected.

Another thing is that fread does not \0 terminate anything it reads, maybe you tried to zero terminate the buffer by the call "bzero" but if you read the whole BUFFSIZE number of bytes the buffer will not have room for a trailing \0

Instead just do a loop and print each character or the ascii value:

```
do 
{
  bytes_read = fread( &buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFSIZE, fd );
  fprintf(stdout, "buffer contents:");
  for ( i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i)
  {
    fprintf( stdout, "%2X", buffer[i] );
  }
} 
while (!feof(fd));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing? How can I modify that fprintf statement to append each character to the end of another character array? I'm really desperate to finish this. Thank you.

Comment: Use `sprintf` and `strcat` to build the values into a string.